# How to fully disable swagger-ui in spring-boot?(/swagger-ui.html should return 404)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I have read following topic:
[Disabling Swagger with Spring MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27976261/2674303)

and I wrote:

```
@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.project.name.controller"))
            .paths(PathSelectors.ant("/api/**"))
            .build()
            .apiInfo(apiInfo())
            .enable(false);
}
```

But in case if I try to access swagger ui: `localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html`
I see
[image]

It looks not accurate. Can I fully disabled this URL ? 404 for example or something like this.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

My answer is similar to the answer provided earlier with a slight difference. I usually create a separate spring profile named `swagger`. When I want to enable Swagger, l pass the following VM flag while starting my application, `-Dspring.profiles.active=swagger`. Here is an example of my Swagger configuration,

```
@Profile(value = {"swagger"})
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfiguration {
    ...
}
```

Next time when you try to access `swagger-ui.html` without `swagger` profile, you will get an empty Swagger screen but not 404.

[image]

If you don't want to load the static Swagger UI page at all, you can write a simple controller as shown below,

```
@Profile("!swagger")
@RestController
@Slf4j
public class DisableSwaggerUiController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "swagger-ui.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void getSwagger(HttpServletResponse httpResponse) throws IOException {
        httpResponse.setStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value());
    }
}
```

Now if you try to access `swagger-ui.html` without `swagger` profile, you will get a 404.

Comment: Did you try to access swagger-ui? What did you see?

Comment: I get an empty swagger screen but not 404. Updated my posting.

Comment: Yes, I got approximately the same. Actually browser asks me to type base url. But I want to get 404

Comment: Updated my posting. I got a 404 when I tried with the new controller.

Comment: How are you starting your service?

Answer (score 20):

with swagger 3.0.0 version you can add `springfox.documentation.enabled=false` in corresponding environment profile `application.properties` file.
For example, I have added this to `application-prod.properties` to disable in production (while running the app you must specify the profile using VM args like `-Dspring.profiles.active=prod`)

Comment: This is the best answer anywhere for Swagger UI 3.0.0 and it was not easy to find (See my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67439123/swagger-3-0-0-cant-disable-in-production-without-swaggerconfig-and-profile). It is not even included in SpringFox's migration guide or current documentation. A very simple answer that should be added to SpringFox's documentation and migration guide post-haste. I would like to see a complete list of Spring Boot application properties in SpringFox's documentation also.

Comment: This is the best one !

Comment: When I try this, I get an infinite loop of `Unable to infer base url.` popup errors as the springfox.js script tries to execute the ui, security, & swagger-resources scripts, but can't handle the 404.

Answer (score 10):

Adding onto @Hayden's answer (I don't have enough points to comment..)

According to the springdoc documentation, you can disable both the springdoc api endpoints and swagger-ui using the following properties:

https://springdoc.org/#disabling-the-springdoc-openapi-endpoints

```
# Disabling the /v3/api-docs endpoint
springdoc.api-docs.enabled=false
```

https://springdoc.org/#disabling-the-swagger-ui

```
# Disabling the swagger-ui
springdoc.swagger-ui.enabled=false
```

Comment: this is the most up-to-date answer!

Answer (score 8):

You can externalize the `@EnableSwagger2` to its own `@Configruation` and load it conditionally via a property or profile. e.g.

```
@Profile("!production")
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfiguration{
    //Additional Swagger Beans
```

}

this would activate swagger for any profile that isn't production.

Answer (score 4):

If you dont have Swagger annotations inside controllers... just exclude SwaggerConfig.class and swagger dependencies on build

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>com/company/app/SwaggerConfig.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
                        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 2):

For SpringDoc users, add this to your `application.properties`

```
springdoc.api-docs.enabled=false
```

To disable Swagger only when the `prod` profile is active, add it to your `application-prod.properties` instead

Answer (score 1):

In latest version of spring boot you can add this in yout application.yml :

```
springdoc:
  swagger-ui:
    enabled: false
  api-docs:
    enabled: false
```

So that **swagger-ui** key is used to disable the swagger interface and **api-docs** one is used to disable the route on which the JSON describing your API is served.

In my config I have a **prod** profile wich reads an application-prod.yml containing those lines.

Answer (score 0):

For those that use the code gen:

```java
@Controller
@Profile({"dev", "staging"})
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String index() {
        System.out.println("swagger-ui.html");
        return "redirect:swagger-ui.html";
    }
}
```

And add the file to you .swagger-codegen-ignore else your changes are overwritten on the next maven build

Answer (score 0):

When using **springdoc-openapi-ui** dependency one can disable swagger-ui through the property:

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.enabled=false
```

as stated in [Spring Doc FAQ](https://springdoc.org/faq.html#how-can-i-define-multiple-openapi-definitions-in-one-spring-boot-project).

Answer (score -1):

Just remove dependency.

```xml
<!--<dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>-->
```

It does not affect compiling.