# Prevent Swagger from automatically adding some models

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I build a REST interface using Spring Boot framework. Then, I use Swagger version 2.9.2 to generate the documentation. As you can see from the photo below, Swagger automatically detects a lot of models.

[image: Models]

However, most of them are redundant. Among them, only the `ResponseMessage` is necessary, the rest are just standard Java class.

So, my question is: **how can I tell Swagger which models to expose**?

Here are my Swagger configuration and code snippet of my controller.

```
@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("my.package"))
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()
            .apiInfo(API_INFO)
            .useDefaultResponseMessages(false);
}
```

**Controller:**

```
@PostMapping(value = "/import", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> importData(HttpServletRequest request) {

    // processing...

    return ResponseEntity.created(uri)
        .body(new ResponseMessage(HttpStatus.CREATED, "Your data is being processed"));
}
```

Comment: Not exactly answer to the question but I could selectively remove models using .ignoredParameterTypes() from Docket. I referenced answers from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46651381/is-there-a-way-i-can-stop-springfox-swagger-from-scanning-the-model-classes?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 3):

You can use :

```
@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.package"))
            .paths(PathSelectors.regex("/api.*")).build().apiInfo(apiInfo())
            .ignoredParameterTypes(Timestamp.class);
}
```

This worked for me. After specifying the class name in **ignoredParameterTypes**, it was no longer present in swagger ui.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [hidden](http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/apidocs/com/wordnik/swagger/annotations/ApiModelProperty.html#hidden()) attribute of `@ApiModelProperty` to hide any specific property of the model. There is no global setting for it. 
Once you have base-package for swagger scan declared, swagger will generate definitions for all components in the package out of box for you. However, with correct use of set of swagger `annotations`, you can override/customize your swagger documentation. 
Please follow these great tutorials ([1](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-restful-api-documentation-with-swagger), [2](https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api)) to familiarize yourself with most useful annotations & usage.

> @Api, @ApiOperation, @ApiResponses, @ApiParam, @ApiIgnore, @ApiModel, @ApiModelProperty etc

Comment: That's not my question. I want to hide the whole auto-detected models, not some properties of my model.

Comment: Have you tried using the `@ApiOperation(value = "Some definition", response = MyModel.class)` with `response` attribute to direct to given model and not do the guess work ? I know that's not your question, but what you are asking, there is no global setting for that, you have to use annotations to customize your doc.

Comment: I did. But I want to know how to hide or prevent Swagger from automatically detecting some unnecessary classes, such as `File`, `InputStream`, as you can see on the screenshot.

Comment: I need more information on your package structure, and then more piece of code showing swagger annotation on controller & model classes, to be able to assist.

Comment: Hi Triet,

Were you able figure out answer to your question ??

Comment: Sadly not yet :(

Answer (score 0):

Springfox Swagger2 acquire UI data through GET /v2/api-docs, which will mapping to springfox.documentation.swagger2.web.Swagger2Controller.getDocumentation().So you can just create a bean to take place of 'ServiceModelToSwagger2Mapper':

```
@Primary
@Component
class CustomServiceModelToSwagger2Mapper : ServiceModelToSwagger2MapperImpl() {
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var modelMapper: ModelMapper
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var parameterMapper: ParameterMapper
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var securityMapper: SecurityMapper
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var licenseMapper: LicenseMapper
    @Autowired
    private lateinit var vendorExtensionsMapper: VendorExtensionsMapper

    override fun mapDocumentation(from: Documentation?): Swagger? {
        if (from == null) {
            return null
        }

        val swagger = Swagger()

        swagger.vendorExtensions = vendorExtensionsMapper.mapExtensions(from.vendorExtensions)
        swagger.schemes = mapSchemes(from.schemes)
        swagger.paths = mapApiListings(from.apiListings)
        swagger.host = from.host
// ➡➡➡➡➡➡➡➡➡➡➡➡➡➡➡➡ here
        swagger.definitions = this.modelsFromApiListings(from.apiListings)
        swagger.securityDefinitions = securityMapper.toSecuritySchemeDefinitions(from.resourceListing)
        val info = fromResourceListingInfo(from)
        if (info != null) {
            swagger.info = mapApiInfo(info)
        }
        swagger.basePath = from.basePath
        swagger.tags = tagSetToTagList(from.tags)
        val list2 = from.consumes
        if (list2 != null) {
            swagger.consumes = ArrayList(list2)
        } else {
            swagger.consumes = null
        }
        val list3 = from.produces
        if (list3 != null) {
            swagger.produces = ArrayList(list3)
        } else {
            swagger.produces = null
        }

        return swagger
    }

    private fun fromResourceListingInfo(documentation: Documentation?): ApiInfo? {
        if (documentation == null) {
            return null
        }
        val resourceListing = documentation.resourceListing ?: return null
        return resourceListing.info ?: return null
    }


    /**
     * @see ModelMapper
     */
    internal fun modelsFromApiListings(apiListings: Multimap<String, ApiListing>): Map<String, Model>? {
        val definitions = newTreeMap<String, springfox.documentation.schema.Model>()
        for (each in apiListings.values()) {
// ➡➡➡➡➡➡➡➡➡➡➡➡➡➡➡➡ here
            // definitions.putAll(each.models)
            definitions.putAll(each.models.filter {
                it.value.qualifiedType.startsWith("com.cpvsn")
                        && it.value.type.typeBindings.isEmpty    
            })
        }
        return modelMapper.mapModels(definitions)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this by adding `genericModuleSubstitutes()` in `Docket()`.

Example:

`.genericModelSubstitutes(ResponseEntity.class)` would substitute `ResponseEntity <MyModel>` with MyModel.

[Reference](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/javadoc/2.7.0/springfox/documentation/spring/web/plugins/Docket.html#genericModelSubstitutes(java.lang.Class...))

Answer (score 0):

```
@Bean
UiConfiguration uiConfig() {
    return UiConfigurationBuilder.builder()
            .defaultModelsExpandDepth(-1)
            .build();
}
```

This worked for me.