# How to hide or prevent Springfox from automatically detecting some unnecessary classes, such as File, InputStream, etc?

Tags: java, swagger, springfox

How to configure Springfox to hide unwanted models like File, InputStream, URL, etc. from the Swagger-ui.html page?

Comment: What library/framework do you use - Springfox, JAX-RS + Swagger Core, something else?

Comment: I am using - Springfox

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46654380/7519419